# How to cherry pick range of commits from specific author?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

For example I have such commits:

```
comit1 user1
comit2 user2
comit3 user3
comit4 user1
comit5 user1
comit6 user2
comit7 user1
```

How can I commit commits only from user1?

```
comit1 user1
comit4 user1
comit5 user1
comit7 user1
```

If using cherry-pick is impossible, are there any other solutions using 1,2 commands?

Comment: How many commits are there, and how many are from `user1`?

Comment: @sk_pleasant-EliasHolzmann 100+ commits and about 20 of them from user1

Comment: Easily done in two steps: (1) obtain list of desired commit hash IDs (using any method you like; `git log` and `git rev-list` are the obvious methods). (2) supply this list of hash IDs to `git cherry-pick`, choosing an appropriate order for the cherry picks.

Comment: @torek im not very familiar with git, could you please describe a details in answer?

Comment: See sk_pleasant's answer; note that `$(...)` is a bash-ism. You can get a version of bash for Windows by installing Git for Windows. Bash is a command line interpreter, similar in some ways to CMD.EXE but vastly superior (more like PowerShell in terms of capabilities). Or, you can learn and use PowerShell, which can do this sort of thing too. I don't use Windows, so I use bash.

Answer (score 2):

As there are only ~20 commits by `user1`, you can combine `git cherry-pick` with `git log --author`:

```
git cherry-pick $(git log --pretty="%H" --author "user1" commit1~..commit7)
```

Alternatively, you can also use `git rev-list` instead of `git log` (`git rev-list` is equivalent to git log --pretty="%H" and shorter if you are only interested in the commit hashes – thanks to @RomainValeri for pointing this out!):

```
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --author "user1" commit1~..commit7)
```

Note this **would** fail if there are too many commits by *user1* because the amount of arguments to `git cherry-pick` (one for each commit) would cause a stack overflow. However, [there are workarounds for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command/375482).

Comment: this throws an error fatal: bad revision '$(git', im using windows OS

Comment: Yeah, this only works in a Linux/Unix shell. I'm not a Windows guy, so I can't really help here. I think some Git installers also contain bash (the most popular shell on Linux), if that is the case, you can run the command there.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just as a sidenote, since your sub-command is listing hashes, you might want to use `rev-list` instead of `log` to have the simpler `git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --author="user1" commit1~..commit7)`

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks for the reference about `git rev-list` – didn't know about that command! I've added this to my answer.

Comment: can you separate the `$(` from `git`? That should work: `$( git`. Same thing when writing the closing `)`

Comment: i wonder.... will cherry-pick be able to read the revisions from separate lines the way it will be written by log? Cause you might also try `git log --pretty='%H' blahblahfilter | xargs git cherry-pick`